# parse error in jquery Ajax complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**EDIT:** **I am getting parse error. when displayed the status in ajax complete function. any idea where am i going wrong.**

Ideally i should get the co-ordinates and "this should be displayed" displayed on html page. But only co-ordinates are been displayed. seems link getElementById cannnot find the "t01" id tag. Also when i try to display content variable outside ajax call i get undefined
even though content is global variable.

**HTML code**

```
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://geolocation.webatu.com/Radius.php",
                data: {
                    lat: lat,
                    lon: lon
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                complete: function (response,status) {
                    document.getElementById('t01').innerHTML = status;
                    content = "<ul>";
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                    for (var i in parsed) {
                        content += "<li>" + parsed[i].ClassName + " " + parsed[i].City + "</li>";
                    }
                   
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/U6Rx8/) and got the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

The answer is:

```
'[]'        
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

So it fails on this answer which is not `javascript` code as `JSONP` practice needs.

**Edited(after all comments):**

After some tries I change you code to this([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/U6Rx8/3/)):

```
window.processResults = function (response) {
    //it must be called with response data inside server answer
    var content = "<ul>";
    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
    for (var i in parsed) {
        content += "<li>" + parsed[i].ClassName + " " + parsed[i].City + "</li>";
    }
    document.getElementById('t01').innerHTML = "This should be displayed";
}

function onSuccess(position) {

    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');

    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />';

    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://geolocation.webatu.com/Radius.php?jsonp=processResults",
        data: {
            lat: lat,
            lon: lon
        },
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,//jQuery will not add it own random callback
        jsonpCallback: 'processResults'//name of callback function which server must wrap the response
    });

}
```

You must change response from server. Like this if you service return nothing:

```
processResults('[]');
```

Instead of `'[]'` like now.

It's `JSONP`: you ask for response server with javascript function name which is the callback on your client side and server must wrap it response in this function.

Comment: yaa it wont work for you. You have to send the correct co-ordinates for it. replace the lat and lon in $.ajax data with 19.0734168 and 72.8994698 and you will get the result :) it will give you the result only if you send the correct co-ordinates

Comment: with those co-ordinates you will get the result as                          `'[{"ID":"1","ClassName":"somaiya","City":"mumbai","latitude":"19.073507000000","longitude":"72.899545000000","distance":"0.0127697680676876"},  {"ID":"4","ClassName":"Soamiya2","City":"delhi","latitude":"19.073507000000","longitude":"72.899545000000","distance":"0.0127697680676876"}]'  
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->`

Comment: Yes, but JSONP means than answer is javascript code and jQuery create a script tag with JSONP content. So there is a syntax error at `<!-- Hosting24...` because this is not valid javascript syntax.

Comment: Ohh i got it !! But this  <!Hosting24 is sent by the web hoisting by default ... any solutions ?? And now i got the error  its showing me parse error

Comment: I managed to remove the hoising thing from jsonp response. still the same error.

Comment: Edited the answer, must work if you will make all that I wrote.

Comment: ok got the errors corrected. the first was as you said <!-- hoisting --> and the second was that i had to append my data into a callback function.More details at http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/08/parsererror-jquery-ajax-request-jsonp.html                                                                  thanks a ton for your help and time mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Though that's not a direct solution to your problem consider using jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() since jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.
See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ok thanks a ton dude. i got the error. Its showing me parse error .